# Problem with log in

Tags: 12.04, boot

I can not log in to my ubuntu 12.4, not even as a guest. Every time i try it push me back to log in screen. And it says something like "suitable mode for kernel not found"
I just instal ubuntu few weeks ago and was so happy with it until now. Can someone please help me.

I Solve the problem!!!!

I log in to bash, (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

and it worked for me ;)

Comment: Have you made any modifications on your installation just before the issue appears? For example, installing drivers, updates...etc

Comment: I dont remember I was doing any modifications, maybe I did something by accident Im new to all this

Comment: If you solved the problem, *please post it as an answer yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

When you reach the Login Screen , press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to redirect to Console Mode. 
There login with your username & password and issue the following commands one by one

`sudo service lightdm stop`

`rm ~/.Xauthority`

`sudo service lightdm start`

retry to login now.